# Paypal Ruby SDK not fetching refresh token

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to integrate Future Payments in my iOS using Ruby SDK on server. According to instructions at  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/make-future-payment/     I follow the following procedure:

1. I receive OAuth2 token from mobile client.
2. I use   **FuturePayment.exch_token(oauth2_code)**   to exchange it for refresh and access token.
3. I expect a response similar to what's mentioned in   https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md
4. But I receive just a string which is similar to access token. This is what I got in one of the calls:     **A015IvJ2HjzJgSI-Qve0VXT3LNKEi67KBGplwkGEptj3DCg**
5. I tried using this token immediately to create a FuturePayment object and I succeeded eventually. But the problem is, since I dont get a refresh token, how would I be able to process/create FuturePayments for the same account in later future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in ruby SDK. Please open an issue on github.

Until fix is released, you can make future payment calls.

1. Exchange authorization code with **Tokeninfo** object that has both refresh token and access token by calling ***create_from_authorization_code()***. Use create_from_refresh_token() if you have a refresh token and want to retrieve an access token with it: https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-ruby/blob/master/lib/paypal-sdk/core/openid_connect.rb#L60

Comment: Thanks a bundle, that solved my issue, at least using Tokeninfo object. Will definitely file bug for FuturePayment class.

Comment: by the way, **create_from_authorization_code()** is also aliased as **create()**  :)